# Spark writes duplicated data to postgres

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark, pyspark, jdbc, transactions

I have a spark application (implemented with pyspark) that writes data (using the dataframe api) to postgres. I use JDBC format option, with the org.postgresql.Driver JDBC driver.

EDIT: command being executed:

```
# df is of type pyspark.sql.Dataframe
df.write \
  .mode("overwrite") \
  .format("jdbc") \
  .option("url", MY_DB_URL) \
  .option("truncate", True) \
  .option("dbtable", MY_DB_TABLE) \
  .option("user", MY_USERNAME) \
  .option("password", MY_PASS) \
  .option("driver","org.postgresql.Driver") \
  .option("stringtype", "unspecified") \
  .option("numPartitions", 90) \
  .option("batchsize", 100000) \
  .save()
```

NOTE: tried tuning numPartitions and batchsize, couldn't get different results.

After the app is finished, I find duplicated data in some tables.

I managed to reproduce it by manually killing a VM instance in my cluster while the app is running, enforcing the assumption that an executor dies mid run and somehow same data is being written more than once.

From looking at the driver implementation, docs and other issue pages, they suggest that a partition is committed in a transaction, and since a task works on a single partition, and it is the unit of work in spark - no duplicates should occur.

Any thoughts on this issue, how to deal with it? (preferably applicatively, i want to avoid inserting with a primary key on tables, as it would be significantly slower).

Tried writing a spark dataframe to postgres.
Expected data to be written correctly to postgres, instead - got duplicated records.

Comment: Hey welcome to SO, could you please share some code where you feel the issue is happening, as it would help us to root cause it better.

Comment: Hey @DataWrangler, thanks. Added the code being executed to perform the write. Anything else you think might be helpful?

Comment: Also, are you sure that there are no duplicates in the `dataframe` that you are trying to persist to the database, maybe you can try running some operations on the primany key on the spark dataframe to confirm that ?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. (I ran those experiments, also, since after inserting the data i do create indexes and PKs, if i had duplicates it would have never worked, but this error occurs inconsistently - (presumably when an executor dies))

Comment: Check the row count of the dataframe used for writing to `postgres` and subsequently check the row count by calling `dropDuplicates()` methhod over the dataframe. See if there's any difference.

Comment: @DipanjanMallick - Made sure my original dataframe has no duplicates, even ran some tests with dropDuplicates() before writing the data, and still got duplicated data in postgres.

Comment: You have verified *executor dies mid run and somehow same data is being written more than once.* But is seems you have  committed some rows before your executor dies. This raises the question *how do you **checkpoint** your input data* so as to not resubmit the committed data on restart. Another option would be load all is a single transaction (batch) so all data is committed an no data in committed.

Comment: @Belayer - From what I understand driver's implementation is such that AutoCommit is false, and each task commits its written partition once, at the end. so, transaction should be supported. is that not the case?